# Jquery attr src removes one string from src but not a more complex one, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, vimeo

I'm using jquery to remove src from an embedded vimeo video by clicking on a certain list item. Works fine when i use this embed code in the src string:

```
video1.attr('src','http://player.vimeo.com/video/43550778);
```

However I would rather use a more complex embed code to get rid of some unsightly default embedding settings:

```
video1.attr('src','http://player.vimeo.com/video/43550778?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ababab');
```

This doesn't work. When the list item that triggers this attr to be removed is clicked, it doesn't work. All other functions work with the exception of this. Is there something wrong with this embed code? Some illegal characters? I can't figure it out.

Any help appreciated!

Edit:
I've set up my jquery like this:

```
nav.filter(':nth-child(1)').on( 'click', function(){
        images.filter(':nth-child(1)').slideDown(800).siblings().slideUp(50);
        video2.attr('src','');
        video1.attr('src','http://player.vimeo.com/video/43550778?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=ababab');
    });
```

I'm using the empty src to in effect stop the video as it slides up. As you can see there's also a different video on the page which is also being kept hidden.

Comment: Have you tried `http://player.vimeo.com/video/43550778?title=0&byline=0&portrait=0&color=ababab` ? (I removed the 'amp;'s)

Comment: @TrentSeed click edit and wrap that link in ` (the key above TAB)

Comment: Please show us the code that removes that attribute, not the one that sets it, if that is what you want...

Comment: Works fine for me: [http://jsfiddle.net/x5TQY/](http://jsfiddle.net/x5TQY/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @TrentSeed suggested, you shouldn't need to encode your ampersands as HTML entities in your javascript source. Just use a literal ampersand.

http://jsfiddle.net/xdUMN/

Comment: Thanks Peter, I changed the ampersands to literal ones, but it still isn't working the way it should?

Comment: Post more code for us. Are you sure the selector you use to get the `video1` variable actually matches the element you think it does?

Comment: Sweeeet! That was the problem! i removed the id accidentally. thank you so much. bit stupid of me but still, thank you. Us when we got your answer and it worked: http://25.media.tumblr.com/tumblr_m6ci92AkDN1r4fo7ko1_500.jpg

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me. What's different about your code?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<img src="foobar">

<a href="#" onclick="$('img').attr('src', 'http://player.vimeo.com/video/43550778?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0&amp;color=ababab');">click</a>

<a href="#" onclick="$('img').removeAttr('src');">remove</a>
```

Comment: I've not set the code up quite like this. See my edit above. Cheers!